# Can I use an if statement to detect if bash and dash are being run interactively?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting, dash

After looking around for a while I've found several good pages describing how to check and see if a bash script is running interactively and [there seem to be several methods](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html#IITEST), but one of them that I keep seeing over and over is checking the variable `$-` for the presence of `i` to signify that it is interactive.

I'm looking for a way to use an `if` statement that would work with both `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` (which is typically aliased to `/bin/dash` on Ubuntu systems), or in fewer words
"**an interactive `if` test that is universal as possible**"

For `bash` it seems these things should work:

#### Case Statement

```
case "$-" in
*i*)    echo This shell is interactive ;;
*)  echo This shell is not interactive ;;
esac
```

#### If Statement

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    do_interactive_stuff
fi
```

But `$-` is apparently not set in `dash`. Possibly because `$-` is supposed to be the [Flags passed to script](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#FLPREF) variable which

> was originally a ksh construct adopted into Bash, and unfortunately it does not seem to work reliably in Bash scripts... [ for it's intended purpose however] ...One possible use for it is to have a script self-test whether it is interactive.

#### So is there an (relatively simple) `if` test that can be used both with `bash` and `dash`?

Or am I just "doing it wrong?"

ps: I have been under the impression that `dash` is faster than `bash`, and unless the script needs "bash specific" functions it would be better to hashbang it as `#!/bin/sh` and let it use the system-default shell. I get that checking for an interactive shell in the way mentioned above *is* "bash specific" but it seems odd to think there is not a more universal way. In the script I'm working on I don't need any other bash-specific functionality.

Comment: What makes you think `dash` doesn't set `$-`? Both your `if` and your `case` statements work exactly as you've posted them in `bash`, `bash` called as `sh` (which makes a difference, yes), `zsh`, `csh`, `ksh`, `tcsh`, `fish` _and_ `dash`. I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common (if not utterly foolproof) way to check for an interactive terminal is to check whether `PS1` is set:

```
if [[ -z "$PS1" ]]; then
    echo "Probably run as a script."
else
    echo "Probably interactive."
fi
```

Another alternative is checking for the `i` option in `$-`:

```
case "$-" in
   *i*)
       echo "Probably interactive"
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Probably scripted"
       ;;
esac
```

There is also the `-t` option for `test` (aka `[` and its cousin, `[[`):

```
fd=0 # stdin
if [[ -t "$fd" ]]; then
    echo "Interactive"
else
    echo "Scripted"
fi
```

Tip of the hat to the [Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html).

`dash` and `sh` may not have `[` and `[[` available, so you might have to explicitly use `test`, e. g.:

```
fd=0
if test -t "$fd"; then  # you might need /path/to/test
    echo "Interactive"
else
    echo "Scripted"
fi
```

Since `test` is its own binary, I'm pretty certain that anything using `test -t` is shell-agnostic.

Comment: `test -t` has nothing to do with being interactive or not, it has to do with being connected to a terminal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced alternatives